# Algorithm to find k neighbors in a certain range?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor, point-clouds

Suppose there is a point cloud having 50 000 points in the x-y-z 3D space. For every point in this cloud, what algorithms or data strictures should be implemented to find k neighbours of a given point which are within a distance of [R,r]? Naive way is to go through each of the 49 999 points for each of the 50 000 points and do a metric testing. But this approach will take large time. Just like there is kd tree to find nearest neighbour in small time so is there some real-time DS/algo implementation out there to pre-process the point clouds to achieve the goal inn shortest time?

Comment: pre-process? Just go through it once and store a list of indexes for each point that is close. O(n^2) but if you're only doing it once, 50k points isn't a huge amount.

Comment: @twentylemon I miscommunicated my problem. Refer the edits and suppose n=200 000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is part of the topic of [Nearest Neighbor Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), or more precisely, [k-Nearest Neighbor Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#k-nearest_neighbor). The answer to your question depends on the data structure you are using to store the points. If you use [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or variants like [R*-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree), and you are doing multiple searches on your database, you will likely find a substantial performance improvement in two or three-dimensional space compared with naive linear search. In higher dimensions, space partitioning schemes tend to underperform linear search.

Answer (score 1):

As some answers already suggest for NN search you could use some tree algorithm like [k-d-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). There are implementations available for all programming languages.

If your description `[R,r]` suggests a hollow sphere you should compare one-time-testing (within interval) vs. two stages (test-for-outer and remove samples that pass test-for-inner).

You also did not mention performance requirements (timing or frame rate?) and your intended application (feasible approach?).

Comment: My intended application is to find all possible contact points on a given point cloud via a 2-finger parallel jaw gripper. O(n^2) seems too much time. Can i have some O(n logn) type efficiency?

Comment: the trees should have O(n log n). have a look at the [point cloud library](http://pointclouds.org/). for 3 dimensions the octree might fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ordinary Euclidean metric, you could go through the list three times and extract those points that within R in each dimension, essentially extracting the enclosing cube.  Searching the resulting list would still be O(n^2), but on a much smaller n.

Comment: Extracting the 2R cube is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

There are efficient algorithms (in average, for random data), see [Nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

Your approach is not efficient, yet simple.

Please read through, check you requirements and get back so we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I am interested in : Fixed-radius near neighbors. However, if the fixed radius could be variable radius, ii would work better.

Comment: Yes i would like to use variable radius.

Comment: If you choose an appropitiate data structure you might succeed. You need to make sure that it does not add considerable complexity.

Comment: Could you suggest such data structures?